# ImportError: cannot import name 'walk' from 'puresnmp' (/home/rojin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/puresnmp/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, snmp

I am trying to import walk from pure snmp but I am getting this import error. Most likely due to circular import? but I cannot seem to fix it. I am using python 3.10.6 on ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I tried reinstalling and import in various ways but I always get the same error. I am thinking of downgrading the python version maybe but I do not if it is the right way.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

from puresnmp import walk

IP = "10.10.10.254"
COMMUNITY = 'public'
OID = '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2'

for row in walk(IP, COMMUNITY, OID):
    print(row)

IP = "10.10.10.254"
COMMUNITY = 'public'
OID = '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8'

for row in walk(IP, COMMUNITY, OID):
    print(row)
    
#Indiviaual Reason on Switch/Router

g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10113')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Indiviaual Reason on Switch/Router

g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10113')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Reboot Reason on Switch/Router
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.2.0')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

#System Uptime on Switch/Router
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

#Power Value
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.5.1.3.1006')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

#FAN Value
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.4.1.3.1007')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

#System Temperature Value
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3.1008')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Monitoring CPU on Switch/Router
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.58.0')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Monitoring Memory on Switch/Router
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6.1')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Version Detail of Switch/Router
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))


#Total Number of Interfaces/Vlan
g = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'), UdpTransportTarget(
        ('10.10.10.254', 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0')))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Comment: https://github.com/exhuma/puresnmp/issues You might go to its vendor. It's not a main stream SNMP library for Python (1% day downloads of PySNMP), so you shouldn't expect too many users are here to answer your inquiries.

Comment: can you post the error message and strack trace?